# Split jobs among ipyparallel engines to make external n-threaded calls

Tags: ipython, external, ipython-parallel

#### The problem

Say I have 20 processors available. I want to pass arguments to an external
program from IPython that runs best with 4 threads at a time, and use map_async to keep adding jobs until all jobs are finished. Below is example code where I believe just one process would be assigned to each job at a time. Is this an example where you would use the 'chunksize' flag? It seems that would do the opposite, i.e., send multiple jobs to one processor.

#### Start engines outside of IPython

```
ipcluster start -n 20 --daemon
```

#### IPython code

```
import ipyparallel as ipp
import subprocess


def func(args): 
    """ function that calls external prog w/ 4 threads """
    subprocess.call([some_external_program, args, nthreads=4])


args = [...]
ipyclient = ipp.Client().load_balanced_view()  
results = ipyclient.map_async(func, args)  
results.get()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a task is multithreaded, you don't want to be running it on too many engines. If this is the bulk of your work, it is probably best to start `n_cpus/n_threads` engines instead of `n_cpus` (5 engines in your case of 20 CPUs, 4 threads). If it's a subset of your work that's multithreaded like this, then you may want to just restrict *their* assignment to `n_cpus/n_threads`. You can do this with the `targets` argument when creating a view, which will restrict task assignment to a subset of engines:

```
n_threads = 4
client = ipp.Client()
all_view = client.load_balanced_view() # uses all engines
threaded_view = client.load_balanced_view(targets=client.ids[::n_threads])
```

This assumes that you have one engine per CPU on a single machine. If you are using multiple machines or the engine count has a different relationship to the number of CPUs, you will have to work out the correct subset of engines to use. Targets can be any manually specified list of engine IDs.